# mount network drive as guest

Tags: networking, samba, storage, fstab

I'm trying to mount the network drive, so far I've got:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm //192.168.1.1 /media/plex
```

but I get:

```
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I'm not really sure how to mount the disk as guest, all the examples I've seen provide some form of credentials. The end goal is to have this disk automount via the `fstab`

```
//192.168.1.1 /media/plex cifs guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm 0 0
```

but that gives the same error. I can mount the disk perfectly with finder on my mac `cmd-k` and `smb://192.168.1.1` mounts the network drive?

Any pointers on what I'm not getting right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: We found that the Mac was automatically adding a directory name to the mount path, //192.168.1.1/volume, so we need to make the equivalent change to the linux mount command and presumably the fstab.

==================

Check this out:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/427044/mounting-cifs-drive-gives-mount-error22-invalid-argument

Particularly the response with the green checkmark (about the mount URL) and
the one that explains how to check the log. Maybe that will give you a push in the right direction.

Comment: man, that is irritating! the mount on my mac wasn't actually what I was putting in, it was automatically adding the route mount directory. which in my case happened to be `//192.168.1.1/volume`. Can you update your answer @MartinMarty?